# How to make the widgets on the popup window widgets stay with the popup window when the root window is resized

Tags: python, kivy

The widgets on my popup window do not resize when the root window resizes. The popup window and the labels on the popup window stay where they are. Does it have something to do with the size_hint and size of the popup window itself? It seems that the widgets(icons) are independent of the popup window.

main file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MainScreen(Screen, FloatLayout):
    mantra_text = ObjectProperty(None)

    def printMantra(self):
        print(self.ids.mantra_text.text)

    def icon_popup(self):
        popup = Popup(title="Profile Icon", content=Popup_Content(), size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 200))
        popup.open()


class Popup_Content(FloatLayout):
    pass


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

    def set_profile_icon(self, image):
        self.root.ids.profile_icon.source = image.source
        print(image)
        #print(self.root.ids.profile_icon)


MainApp().run()
```

kivy file

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<MainScreen>
    Popup_Content:
        id: popup_content

    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffbb99")
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.6, "top":1}
            size_hint: 0.4,0.2
            spacing_horizontal: [0.9*root.width]
            Label:
                text: "Name"
            ImageButton:
                id: profile_icon
                source: "profile_icon"
                on_release: root.icon_popup()

        Label:
            text: mantra_text.text
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 25
        TextInput:
            id: mantra_text
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.15, "top":0.6}
            size_hint: 0.7, 0.1
            #text_size: self.size

        Label:
            text: "Time"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.6}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            text: "Time"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.5}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
            on_release: root.printMantra()

<Popup_Content>

    #profile_icon: profile_icon
    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.95, "y":1.6}

            ImageButton:
                id: man_01
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon(man_01)
            ImageButton:
                id: man_02
                source: "icons/male_icon_02.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon(man_02)
            ImageButton:
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon()
            ImageButton:
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon()
            ImageButton:
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon()
            ImageButton:
                id: female_01
                source: "icons/female_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon(female_01)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `Popup` to change size when you resize the `App`, then use `size_hint`. Something like:

```
popup = Popup(title="Profile Icon", content=Popup_Content(), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
```

Using `size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 200)` forces the `Popup` size to `(300, 200)` regardless of the size of `MainScreen`.

And to get the `Popup` `content` to follow the `Popup`, you can use `RelativeLayout`. In the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html) for `RelativeLayout`, it says:

> When a widget with position = (0,0) is added to a RelativeLayout, the
> child widget will also move when the position of the RelativeLayout is
> changed. The child widgets coordinates remain (0,0) as they are always
> relative to the parent layout.

So if you define your `Popup_Content` as a `RelativeLayout`, then the `GridLayout` will follow it. I suggest defining `Popup_Content` as:

```
class Popup_Content(RelativeLayout):
    pass
```

Then, in the `kv`:

```
<Popup_Content>
    #profile_icon: profile_icon
    GridLayout:
        cols: 5
        # pos_hint: {"x":0.95, "y":1.6}
    
        ImageButton:
            id: man_01
            .
            .
            .
```